# deprecated gradle plugins after updating flutter and upgrading my firebase dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I got this error when building the app for android and i can not figure how to update those gradle plugins, i tried to flutter clean and flutter build but with no success and i am fearing to edit gradle files with something i do not understand so i will make the problems more worse so if someone had solution or a way to do this ?

```
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\lastDoserFirmwareFromIOS-20-02-2024-slow-connection-wifi-Disconnect\egyreef_smart_doser\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
  ...
}

Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Note: C:\Users\gendi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\cloud_firestore-4.15.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a 
deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             71.3s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          15.2s
D/FirebaseAuth(25952): Notifying id token listeners about user ( W9li95ooO1TdDJZTgejmJMkm9jm1 ).
Syncing files to device RMX3269...                                 174ms
```

and here is my flutter doctor

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] Network resources
```

my build.grale is here also

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
 }


android {
    namespace "com.example.egyreef_smart_doser"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.egyreef.smartonlinedoser"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

   apply plugin:  'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my setting.gradle is

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

i tried flutter clean and flutter build but no help

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to upgrade your gradle files is delete your android folder and open terminal set path to the project root directory and run

```
flutter create .
```

> NOTE

Add those changes again if you have made any changes in android files.